# respond_to :json + respond_with + except (for all actions)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3

AlbumsController:

```
respond_to :json

def index
  respond_with albums.ordered
end
```

Now how can I make it so that the underlying call `to_json` always executes with this options: `except => [:created_at, :updated_at]`? And I don't mean just for this action, but for all others actions defined in this controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The as_json method is what is used to serialize into json

```
class Album

  def as_json(params={})
    params.merge! {:except=>[:created_at, :updated_at]}
    super(params)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define `serializable_hash` on your model which defines the keys and values to return. Rails will then return JSON / XML based on this hash:

```
def serializable_hash
  { :name => "Stack Overflow",
    :created_at => created_at",
    :posts_count => posts.count
  }
end
```